# Three js, what is toArray

Tags: javascript, three.js

I got a question while reading three.js documentation and an example from there.

The source code I got shows.

```
        var positions = new Float32Array( vertices.length * 3 );
        var colors = new Float32Array( vertices.length * 3 );
        var sizes = new Float32Array( vertices.length );

        var vertex;
        var color = new THREE.Color();

        for ( var i = 0, l = vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

            vertex = vertices[ i ];
            vertex.toArray( positions, i * 3 );


            color.setHSL( 0.01 + 0.1 * ( i / l ), 1.0, 0.5 );
            color.toArray( colors, i * 3 );

            sizes[ i ] = PARTICLE_SIZE * 0.5;

}
```

Firstly, I guessed 'toArray' in the following line

> vertex.toArray( positions, i*3)

an argument to store position values into an array that the length of the array would be very long
after the for loop.
However, it wasn't. I checked it using console.log.
only the last value was stored in 'vertex'. I looked into three js for that but it only shows that it's the method for handling vector.

Does anyone know the meaning and usage of toArray?

Comment: if you want to see how the data changes in the vertex in log, then use in the loop this for example: `console.log(vertex.clone());`

Comment: is clone() jquery argument?

Comment: no, it's a method of `THREE.Vector3()`

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a quick way to store a vector (or color) in an array, i.e :

```
// vertex.toArray( positions, i * 3 );
positions[i * 3] = vertex.x;
positions[i * 3 + 1] = vertex.y;
positions[i * 3 + 2] = vertex.z;
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r114/src/math/Vector3.js#L688